# Find all existing online meetings via MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to get attendance reports for historic online meetings in MS Teams (e.g. of the last day) that where created via UI (not via API). I have a client (service) with the required permissions to do the Graph API calls. The client runs in application context not in context of an user.

My first idea was to get a list of online meetings by using this request:

```
GET /v1.0/communications/onlineMeetings/
```

But it's not a valid request without the `$filter` parameter.

Other ways (e.g. via a calendar of an user) didn't work too. It seams that there is no way to access meetings that where created by UI. Am I right?

Is there another way to find all online meeting ids? Or just to directly access the attendance reports?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. It seems that a date range is also inadmissible as a filter.  Using any of [videoTeleconferenceId, meeting ID, joinWebURL, or joinMeetingId] seems to work.  The joinWebURL exists in any Calendar event with an associated OnlineMeeting, so presumably one solution is to search for all calendar events with

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with a similar problem. I did not find a way to get meetingIDs directly. However there appear to be 4 unique properties for the onlineMeeting object. They are the ones listed in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get[GET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get%5BGET) onlineMeeting documentation][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get). The filters are listed as examples, but AFAICT are a definitive list:

- videoTeleconferenceId
- meeting ID
- joinWebURL
- joinMeetingId

Add the error message I get from the delegated endpoint:

`"message": "Filter expression expected - /onlineMeetings?$filter={ParameterName} eq '{id}'.",`

in particular `eq '{id}'` suggests the API endpoint can only return a single record.

So the question becomes how to get one of those 4 unique identifiers. When I use outlook to a create an event with an online meeting, the graphAPI returns an event with `{"onlineMeeting": {"joinWebURL": "https://teams.microsoft.com/..."}}` embedded.  Other methods of creating calendar events which include a link to an online meeting likely also populate this field.

**One solution is to search for all events with joinWebURL set, then loop through each event with a separate call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me /onlineMeeting$filter=joinWebURL eq <joinWebURL>`.**

This is super inefficient, and I would not want to do this with a large number of events. I may not have a choice.

I hoped to use the graphAPI's `$expand` query string (`$expand=onlineMeeting`), but that returns an error that the property is not navigable, meaning it does not designate a relationship for the data.  This is disappointing hole in the graphAPI's implementation, IMO.

CAVEAT: I personally have only been able to get results from `/onlineMeeting` using the delegated API endpoint. The application endpoint always returns "unknown error". Hopefully this can be r